# Not able to find the Developer Tab from Magento Backend

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.redlightblinking.com/blog/magento-debugging-how-to-debug-template-paths-logging-and-display-errors) to enable the debugging mode in Magento but i can't see any option like in the tutorial described to locate from system > configuration. But i can't find the developer Tab or anything like that.

I don't know if there is any option to hide that. Here is attached the screen shot of my Admin configuration section:

[image]

**Anybody please help me to enable the debugging mode**, even i tried to searched another tutorials but everyone talking to Developer menu into the configuration option.

Comment: Seems that your backend user isn't allowed to see that menu items.

Comment: It should be after your "Advanced" link on the left. Are you sure that your user role is "administrator"? Can you edit user roles via System->Authorizations-> Users/Roles ? If so, this should be a mod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a permissions issue with the role that you're logged into. In the database, check this table admin_rule and see if you have any 'deny' records returned using this query:

select * from admin_rule where resource_id = 'admin/system/config/advanced'